# Does currentTime method in video.js have browser compatibility problems?

Tags: video, browser, video.js

When I use video.js in secondary development of H5 video playing, the video works well. But when using a different browser to see corresponding time frame by frame I will find picture is not coherence. Then I found that if I use the currentTime method to set a time and get the time again, I will get two different values. So what causes such a situation? Thank you for your answer.
Example: currentTime(8.04), I will get 8.039999.

Answer (score 0):

frame accurate seeking within a browser is not usably possible. And while it MAY work on some browsers, sometimes, it shouldn't be relied upon. The browser is only required to implement a high level API to be compatible with the web standards. The details are up to the browsers them selves. As for 8.04 -> 8.03999 that is basic computer science see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic